# Asymptote to graph of solution to $60y' = y[12 - y]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$60P'(t) = P(t)[12 - P(t)]$, and $P(0) = 3$. What is the horizontal asymptote for the graph of the function $P(t)$?  The answer is "$y = 12$."  The answer is the same if the initial condition is $20$ or $100$.  What is the solution to the differential equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y=P(t)$. Then 
$$\begin{align}60y'=y(12-y)&\implies\frac{60}{y(12-y)}\frac{dy}{dt}=1\tag1\\
\int\frac5y+\frac{5}{12-y}dy&=\int dt\tag2\\
5\log y-5\log(12-y)&=t+c\tag3\\
\log\frac{12-y}{y}&=-\frac15t+c\tag4\\
12-y&=Aye^{-t/5}\tag5\\
y&=\frac{12}{1+Ae^{-t/5}}\tag6\end{align}$$

As $t\to\infty$, $y\to \frac{12}{1+Ae^{-"\infty"}}=\frac{12}{1+0}=12.$

Also notice that the initial condition allows us to determine $A$, which has no affect on this asymptote, as you noted, since $Ae^{-t/5}\to0$ as $t\to\infty$ regardless of $A$.

---

Steps:

$(1)$ - Re-arrange differential equation

$(2)$ - Split into partial fractions, integral signs

$(3)$ - integrate

$(4)$ - log rules

$(5)$ and $(6)$ - rearrange

Comment: Nice explanation!

Comment: My post was part a.) of a past AP Calculus test.  Part b.) is to find the value of the function at which the function is growing the fastest if P(0)=3.  The solution provided says "half of the maximum population is when the population is growing the fastest, and lim P(t) = 12.  So, when the function value is 6, the function is growing the fastest."  That was it.

Comment: @user74973 I am not sure about the method you mentioned. This is how I would do it. If $P(0)=3$, then $A=3$. $$P(t)=\frac{12}{1+3e^{-t/5}}\implies P'(t)=\frac{36e^{-t/5}}{5(1+3e^{-t/5})^2}\implies P''(t)=-\frac{36e^{-t/5}(1-3e^{-t/5})}{25(1+3e^{-t/5})^3}$$

This is zero when $e^{-t/5}=\frac13\implies t=5\log 3$.

Then $P(5\log3)=\frac{12}{1+1}=6.$

Comment: Yes, this is the way I got the answer while waiting for your reply.  Thanks.

Comment: You have an error in your definition of $P^{\prime\prime}$.  The numerator should have 108 and not 36.  (I had supposed that $P(0) = 1$ when I defined $P^{\prime}$ and $P^{\prime\prime}$.  This is a mistake.  In the post, I specify $P(0) = 3$.)

Comment: @user74973 Oh I see, well the constant doesn't affect the final answer anyway, since the stationary point only depends on the $(1-3e^{-t/5})$ term. I don't see any harm in keeping my last comment, since you've seen where the change should be made. But feel free to delete any comments of yours which are wrong / not useful.